# How do i learn default system encoding of a solaris zone?

Tags: character-encoding, solaris, collation, solaris-10

In a solaris zone, i want to learn default system charset and collation in the terminal.
I searched on google a bit, but i couldn't find.
I used `locale` command, but it gives me all settings and it is not what i need.
Btw, i want to learn this in the terminal, because i only have ssh connection to that zone.
Thx in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate on why the `locale` command doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: when i make ssh connection to the remote solaris zone and run `locale` command, i'm getting following output;

`LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=`

and when my friend makes remote connection to the that solaris zone and run `locale` command, he is getting following output;

`LANG= LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=`

Comment: i need that because, we have a software component which runs great in our local development machines (ubuntu 10.04 linux) and which has utf-8 as default charset; but we deployed the product in that zone and we encounter charset issues :(

Answer (score 2):

The default locale is just this, a default value. It can be set in `/etc/default/init`. If not set there, the C locale is used. Shell initialization files (eg: `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile` and the likes) are free to override the default with a different value. Either one or both of you and your friend are doing that.

If you want your application to use a specific locale and character encoding instead of the current one, just set it before launching your application.

eg:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 myApplication
```

Comment: The "default" and there is such a thing, is the "C" locale or POSIX locale.  If the LC environment variables are not set explicitly some where you are supposed have POSIX or C locale.

Comment: Please guide on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597534/unable-to-read-japanese-file-on-sunos-5-1